# Visual Studio Team Services ignore files

Tags: tfs, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I'm transpiling TypeScript files from my web project into wwwroot as part of my gulp build.  I want Visual Studio Team Services to ignore the output js files in wwwroot, but it constantly detects them as added files and I have to undo.  The server is @visualstudio.com.  In my wwwroot folder I have a .tfignore file with the following text, which should ignore all files in these folders:

```
lib\*.*
app\*.*
```

I have also attempted to add a .tfignore file at the higher level (project root), just to see if I could get it to ignore js files:

```
wwwroot\app\**\*.js
```

I've also added the following lines to my .xproj, which seems to have no effect.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DnxInvisibleFolder Include="wwwroot\app\" />
    <DnxInvisibleFolder Include="wwwroot\lib\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

How do I ignore these folders/files?  This is a VS2015 / Asp.net 5 project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with tfignore file for ASP.NET5 project. Refer to this issue on GitHub for details: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/18